# pinging walls2windows.com returns bad destination from some places

Tags: ping

Whenever I ping walls2windows.com at network-tools.com, I get bad destination even though the URL is about 1 month old now and works here.
It also doesnt ping at ping.eu/ping

DNS and A record IPs are supposedly mapped correctly.

Comment: +1 for providing the real domain name, not `example.com`

Answer (score 1):

Using DNSStuff's DNS report tool shows some problems contacting the name servers for your domain. Here's the info from DNSStuff:

---

Your NS records at the parent servers are:

fiz.dizwiz.biz. [67.15.253.220 (NO GLUE)] [US]

giz.dizwiz.biz. [74.54.56.231 (NO GLUE)] [US]

liz.dizwiz.biz. [67.15.253.219 (NO GLUE)] [US]

tiz.dizwiz.biz. [74.52.140.83 (NO GLUE)] [US]

[These were obtained from j.gtld-servers.net]

---

ERROR: Some of your nameservers listed at the parent nameservers did not respond. The ones that did not respond are:
74.54.56.231

Comment: I hope this has nothing to do  with the fact that the nameserver names are fiz, giz, liz, tiz and not the normal recommended names, ns1, ns2, ns3 and ns4.

Comment: Well, fiz.dizwiz.biz doesn't sound like they take things too seriously, but you never know.